# Create cookies in browser based on object structure

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to create several cookies on a web page based on data that's been read by Puppeteer. From my understanding, I can create cookies with `document. cookie` in Javascript much like the following:

```js
document.cookie = "name=oeschger; SameSite=None; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; Secure";
```

However I can't find any way to create the above string based on an Object, or would I have to manually create some kind of function to effectively build up a cookie-based on key/value pairs from my array of objects?

My data looks like this:

```
[
  {
      "name": "cookiename",
      "value": "1",
      "domain": "mydomain",
      "path": "/",
      "expires": 1628089842,
      "size": 30,
      "httpOnly": false,
      "secure": false,
      "session": false,
      "sameParty": false,
      "sourceScheme": "NonSecure",
      "sourcePort": 80
  },
  {
      "name": "cookiename",
      "value": "1",
      "domain": "mydomain",
      "path": "/",
      "expires": 1628089842,
      "size": 30,
      "httpOnly": false,
      "secure": false,
      "session": false,
      "sameParty": false,
      "sourceScheme": "NonSecure",
      "sourcePort": 80
  }
]
```

Comment: _"would I have to manually create some kind of function"_ - yes. Unless you found a package which has already done it for you. (SO isn't the place to ask for recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let arr = [
         {
          name: "cookiename",
          value: "1",
          domain: "mydomain",
          path: "/",
          expires: 1628089842,
          size: 30,
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: false,
          session: false,
          sameParty: false,
          sourceScheme: "NonSecure",
          sourcePort: 80
          },
      {
          name: "cookiename",
          value: "1",
          domain: "mydomain",
          path: "/",
          expires: 1628089842,
          size: 30,
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: false,
          session: false,
          sameParty: false,
          sourceScheme: "NonSecure",
          sourcePort: 80
      }
    ]

    const addCookies = () => {
      arr.map((i) => {
        document.cookie = i.name, i.value/*ect...*/
      })
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      addCookies();
    })
```

Comment: Why remove the text? It was helpful

Comment: There was a slight mistake i had made, just updated it for you :)